# Python Tutor + Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

**Preambula.**
I'm trying to use Google Colab to teach students Python.
The problem is, there is no nice tool to visualize code execution.
I tried to use Python Tutor by integrating it with the Google Colab, namely created a "magic command"

```py
from IPython.core.magic import  Magics, magics_class, cell_magic, line_magic

@magics_class
class Helper(Magics):

  def __init__(self, shell=None,  **kwargs):
    super().__init__(shell=shell, **kwargs)

  @cell_magic
  def debug_cell_with_pytutor(self, line, cell):
    import urllib.parse
    url_src = urllib.parse.quote(cell)
    str_begin = '<iframe width="1000" height="500" frameborder="0" src="https://pythontutor.com/iframe-embed.html#code='
    str_end   = '&cumulative=false&py=3&curInstr=0"></iframe>'
    import IPython
    from google.colab import output
    display(IPython.display.HTML(str_begin+url_src+str_end))

get_ipython().register_magics(Helper)
```

that can be later used as

```py
%%debug_cell_with_pytutor

total_list = []
for i in range(3):
  total_list.append(i)
total_list
```

**The problem.**
There are actually two problems:

- Python Tutor often refuses to process not-so-complicated code like creating a class with few methods. On the other hand, I was able to start Python Tutor locally and it did not fail.
- I'm not happy with the fact that two different Pythons are used -- the one in Colab and the one in Python Tutor

**What help am I seeking for.**
I would like to either start Python Tutor in Google Colab, or find any other nice visualization tool that may work in Colab.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

At the end of the day I was able to find some solution, but it is quite messy.
I'll be glad if anyone proposes something better.

At the moment the code looks like

```py
#@title #Helper functions (debugger)

!curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fbeilstein/machine_learning/master/pytutor/data_begin.html
!curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fbeilstein/machine_learning/master/pytutor/data_end.html
!curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fbeilstein/machine_learning/master/pytutor/pg_encoder.py
!curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fbeilstein/machine_learning/master/pytutor/pg_logger.py

from IPython.core.magic import  Magics, magics_class, cell_magic, line_magic

@magics_class
class Helper(Magics):

  def __init__(self, shell=None,  **kwargs):
    super().__init__(shell=shell, **kwargs)
    with open('data_begin.html', 'r') as f_in:
      lines = f_in.readlines()
      self.begin_debug = "".join(lines)
    with open('data_end.html', 'r') as f_in:
      lines = f_in.readlines()
      self.end_debug = "".join(lines)

  @cell_magic
  def debug_cell_with_pytutor(self, line, cell):
    import json
    import bdb
    from pg_logger import PGLogger
    import IPython
    from google.colab import output

    def cgi_finalizer(input_code, output_trace):
      ret = dict(code=input_code, trace=output_trace)
      json_output = json.dumps(ret, indent=None) # use indent=None for most compact repr
      display(IPython.display.HTML("<html>" + self.begin_debug + json_output + self.end_debug + "</html>"))


    logger = PGLogger(cumulative_mode=False,
                  heap_primitives=False, 
                  show_only_outputs=False, 
                  finalizer_func=cgi_finalizer,
                  disable_security_checks=True,
                  allow_all_modules=True,
                  probe_exprs=False)

    try:
      logger._runscript(cell)
    except bdb.BdbQuit:
      print("INTERNAL ERROR OCCURED")
    finally:
      logger.finalize()

## use ipython load_ext mechanism here if distributed
get_ipython().register_magics(Helper)
```

Helper files are stored in my GitHub repository for the ML course.
I created them basing on [GraphTerm](https://github.com/mitotic/graphterm/tree/master/graphterm/bin/pytutor) ideas and sources from [PyTutor repository](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor).
You can find some examples of usage in Lecture two "Python", but there's quite a lot of material, thus it may take some time to find them.

Comment: python tutor is open source and available on git hub. Maybe you could fork it and then some how run it locally for your own needs or at least extract out the parts of it you want. https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor

Comment: Couldn't you use Pygame? I would think that being able to draw things on the screen could help a lot, especially for kids. That seems to be why Khan Academy went with p5.js to teach programming on their platform.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle , I tried, but I failed. My first attempt was to start a bottle server in Colab and I even got an html front page from it, but it can't load JS files and JSON with data (i.e. I don't know how to "render" it on Google servers so that it contained all the JS needed and so on). On a second attempt I was able to generate JSON that contains description of what to visualize (Python Tutor generates JSON, than renders pictures according to it), but I don't have any idea how to draw from it something similar to what I see in Python Tutor.

Comment: @AugustBorne , I checked it, but I'm not sure if Pygame contains such a visual debugger as I need. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, maybe I'll be able to use it in some other project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an alternative visualization tool to Python Tutor for Python3 code execution, then I suggest looking at [memory_graph](https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/). It runs locally and therefore avoids many of the limitations of Python Tutor (program size, number of cycles, available imports). I don't know how easy it is to set up in Google Colab but it has just the Graphviz library as dependency.

If you want to visualize every execution step of a program, you probably want to set for example `memory_graph.render(locals(), "visualization.png")` as a 'watchpoint' in some debugger tool and show the "visualization.png" image in Colab somehow.

Example code:

```py
import copy
a = [ [1, 2], ['a', 'b'] ]
c1 = a
c2 = copy.copy(a) # equivalent to:   a.copy() a[:] list(a)
c3 = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

[image]

Full disclosure: I am the developer of [memory_graph](https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/).

Comment: Thank you! That looks very promising. Maybe I'll be able to replace pytutor

Answer (score -1):

Try your existing code (the following part) with `%%debug_cell_with_pytutor` before it:

```
from IPython.core.magic import  Magics, magics_class, cell_magic, line_magic

@magics_class
class Helper(Magics):

  def __init__(self, shell=None,  **kwargs):
    super().__init__(shell=shell, **kwargs)

  @cell_magic
  def debug_cell_with_pytutor(self, line, cell):
    import urllib.parse
    url_src = urllib.parse.quote(cell)
    str_begin = '<iframe width="1000" height="500" frameborder="0" src="https://pythontutor.com/iframe-embed.html#code='
    str_end   = '&cumulative=false&py=3&curInstr=0"></iframe>'
    import IPython
    from google.colab import output
    display(IPython.display.HTML(str_begin+url_src+str_end))

get_ipython().register_magics(Helper)
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)